# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, I can't find what's wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE sangre
(    id_pruebas    VARCHAR2(10)
         CONSTRAINT san_id_pruebas_pk    PRIMARY KEY,
     tipo VARCHAR2(5)    NOT NULL
         CONSTRAINT san_tipo_pruebas  CHECK (tipo = 'O-' OR 
         tipo = 'O+' OR tipo = 'A-' OR tipo = 'A+' OR tipo = 'B-'
         tipo = 'B+' OR tipo = 'AB-' OR tipo = 'AB+'),
     fecha DATE  NOT NULL,
     id_sal    VARCHAR2(1O) NOT NULL,
     id_paciente    NUMBER(8) NOT NULL
         CONSTRAINT san_id_paciente_ck  CHECK (id_paciente >= 0),
     id_enfermero    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT san_id_enfermero_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_enfermero)
         REFERENCES enfermero (id_enfermero),
         CONSTRAINT san_id_paciente_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_paciente)
         REFERENCES paciente(id_paciente),
         CONSTRAINT san_tipo_pruebas_pk FOREIGN KEY (id_sal)
         REFERENCES laboratorio(id_sal));
```

I have checked all parenthesis and previous code that i have made (similar to this) and I just cant find what is wrong.

Comment: Ever try sqldeveloper? Its syntax helper is pretty good and it has a sql text formatter that's also pretty good.

Comment: no, would this help my issue? I am desperate and a noob.

Comment: sqldeveloper uses a type of Intelligent Code Completion that can often help you finish what you start. It's a bit bulky but so is just about everything else.

Comment: In the absence of such things, a common approach is to cut out large swaths of text until the problem goes away. Then add back text a little bit at a time until it becomes obvious where the problem lies. Another approach is to add newlines. Then, if you have a good ide, it will point you to the line number and offset where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks Jeff Holt, i will take a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `or` after `OR tipo = 'B-'`, and the `VARCHAR2(1O)` after `id_sal` has a letter `O` instead of a number `0`.

This would be easier to spot, to me at least, with the constraints inline and the code laid out more clearly:

```
create table enfermero   (id_enfermero varchar2(10) primary key);
create table paciente    (id_paciente  number       primary key check (id_paciente >= 0));
create table laboratorio (id_sal       varchar2(10) primary key);

create table sangre
( id_pruebas    varchar2(10) constraint san_id_pruebas_pk primary key
, tipo          varchar2(5)  not null   constraint san_id_paciente_ck check (tipo in ('O-', 'O+', 'A-', 'A+', 'B-', 'B+', 'AB-', 'AB+'))
, fecha         date         not null
, id_sal        not null     constraint san_tipo_pruebas_fk references laboratorio (id_sal)
, id_paciente   not null     constraint san_id_paciente_fk  references paciente (id_paciente)
, id_enfermero  not null     constraint san_id_enfermero_fk references enfermero (id_enfermero)
);
```

The check constraint on `id_paciente >= 0` seems to belong on the `paciente` unless there is some more complex business rule in which other tables are allowed to have negative values for `paciente.id_paciente` but `sangre` is not.

I renamed foreign key constraint `san_tipo_pruebas_pk` to `san_tipo_pruebas_fk`.

The long list of `or` conditions in `san_id_paciente_ck` is easier to read as an `in` list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of errors, the most proeminent being:

- missing commas at end of lines
- malformed `PRIMARY KEY` constraint
- typos : `VARCHAR2(1O)` instead of `VARCHAR2(10)`

Consider the following statement, that works fine in **[this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0364df52453a03d5ca9f0ff2f12e521)**:

```
CREATE TABLE sangre(    
    id_pruebas VARCHAR2(10),
        CONSTRAINT san_id_pruebas_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_pruebas),
        tipo VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT san_tipo_pruebas 
            CHECK (tipo IN ('O-', 'O+', 'A-', 'A+', 'B-', 'B+', 'AB-', 'AB+')),
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
        id_sal VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        id_paciente NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT san_id_paciente_ck  
            CHECK (id_paciente >= 0),
        id_enfermero VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT san_id_enfermero_fk 
            FOREIGN KEY (id_enfermero) REFERENCES enfermero (id_enfermero),
        CONSTRAINT san_id_paciente_fk 
            FOREIGN KEY (id_paciente) REFERENCES paciente(id_paciente),
        CONSTRAINT san_tipo_pruebas_pk 
            FOREIGN KEY (id_sal) REFERENCES laboratorio(id_sal)
);
```

Pleas note also that I simplified the `CHECK` constraint on `tipo` by using `IN` instead of `OR`ed conditions.

Also, you might want to consider the following syntax, that shortens the code by inlining the foreign keys and check constraints (the only drawback is that you cannot choose the name of the constraints):

```
CREATE TABLE sangre(    
    id_pruebas VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    tipo VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL   
        CHECK (tipo IN ('O-', 'O+', 'A-', 'A+', 'B-', 'B+', 'AB-', 'AB+')),
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    id_sal VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES laboratorio(id_sal),
    id_paciente NUMBER(8) NOT NULL
        CHECK (id_paciente >= 0)
        REFERENCES paciente(id_paciente),
    id_enfermero VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES enfermero (id_enfermero)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f186985fab972a21d86b6fdffee73cc1)**

Comment: what happends if i dont put `PRIMARY KEY(name of column)`, in the apex examples they skip this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you skipping the ```FOREIGN KEY``` function because it has te same name on both tables?

Comment: @Octupux: the second query demonstrates how to declare *inline* constraints. Does any of both queries work in apex (I am not very familiar with this development environment, and you did not initially mention it in your question)?

Comment: I don't see any missing commas or anything wrong with the OP's PK definition. For example, `create table sangre (id_pruebas varchar2(10) constraint san_id_pruebas_pk primary key);` creates a table `sangre` with a PK named `san_id_pruebas_pk` on `id_pruebas`.